# Honda Odyssey ex-l res anti theft radio code issue

Tags: honda, audio

Battery connection got loose and the radio system got shut off. I fixed the connection by tightening the battery cable (not sure how this happened as my car gets serviced at a honda dealer only). Now everything is good but the radio got locked for this annoying theft protection thingy so I took it to a dealer. They said they couldn't unlock the radio. The radio was working fine until that incident. I came home I tried the radio code on the sticker but it didn't work. When I try to verify the s/n by pressing the preset buttons 1 and 6 at the same time and turning on the audio power but that didn't do the trick. It says "S/N no code". Am I stuck to replace the unit or what? I heard it's expensive and not fair to spend thousands for this type of software logic errors. I bought a brand new car so hard to imagine the radio code and sn on the sticker being wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the dealer if the radio is programmable and if service bulletin 10-081 applies to this model. That is the only thing that has not been tried that I can think of. The serial number is usually on the units label. The unit must be removed to read it. It can be used to obtain the security code, in case the code was incorrect.

I have had these radios take a few tries to accept the security code. I have not had one not have a serial number.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had a chance to take my car to a dealer but I will soon. I will ask about the sb 10-081 and keep it posted for others with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

I got my radio unlocked finally, thank you!! You were right about the 10-081. The symptoms match precisely so I took my car to the dealer. They said they already applied the update back in 2011 and I might have to replace the unit. Of course, I didn't believe them because my radio was working fine until that morning. I was able to check the software update version and it clearly shows that the update was not done. So I tried a different dealer and I begged them to apply the 10-081 update but after several hours they gave up and charged $130; and then told me that I need to replace the unit. Later I found out that they didn't even apply the update..

So I decided to do this myself and did online shopping.. bought the update CD from discoundhondaparts.com. Instruction is simple but I had to turn on the radio first. To turn on the radio for 3 minutes, I could do this 1, 6, power button, then 2 trick and inserted the CD. It started making musical sounds and showed a status bar at the bottom; upon completion, a man voice said "eject" and I did. Finished the update by pressing 1, 2, 3, 5 preset buttons and then pressing and holding the tune button at the bottom until it turns off the radio. I restarted my car and it asked the radio code; instead inserting the radio code, I pressed the power button and held for a few seconds and walla.. it all started working.

I am so happy as I am going camping this weekend and music is a big part of all the fun.. thank you. i will probably complain and try to get my refund on the money I spend for this nonsense.. haha

Answer (score 2):

discoundhondaparts.com no longer exists, a typo?

1+6+PWR may show the serial number, and you may have the correct code, but then it is not accepted by the radio - this is the same firmware bug as no serial number showing up at all.

Start with radio PWR on, press and hold 1+2+3+5, then press and hold ENTER until shutdown/click. This is used to complete a pre-loaded firmware update, but it also resets the Error count, if you tried 9 times already (no need to disconnect the battery or pull fuses to reset).

Start with radio OFF, press and hold 1 & 6, then press PWR (the S/N will show), then 2. The radio will operate normally, but only for 150 seconds ("test mode"). If it is in this mode every time before turning ignition OFF, after about 10 car restarts the radio enters a "dumb mode": radio only (no CD or AUX), manual tuning only. Bluetooth link to a previously coupled phone operates audio only, no dialout or phone control. Do not turn the radio PWR off, as this resets the count.

As per A10-081 Service Bulletin, the following are the recovery/update CDs:

- T/N 07AAZ-TK8A110 (LX)
- T/N 07AAZ-TK8A120 (EX)
- T/N 07AAZ-TK8A130 (EX-L)
- T/N 07AAZ-TK8A140 (EX-L with RES)
- T/N 07AAZ-TK8A100 (Parental Error EX-L with RES)

Note that these are tools not parts, which may matter when ordering. www.hondapartsnow.com seems to list some of these.

In Canada, radio configurations were different, and part numbers with "C" instead of "A" are not interchangeable. For example, 2011 Odyssey EX needs

- 07AAZ-TK8C120

As per Canadian Service Bulletin from 2012, "each dealership is shipped a set of the update CDs. The software is also available for download from eBiz under SERVICE TOOLS, Technical Operations, Audio Software, Install Software." As of Dec.2018, no dealer in Canada seems to have any of these CDs, and the eBiz platform has apparently been abandoned in about 2015. It appears that an ebay/wreck-yard replacement radio is the only way to fix it in Canada.

P.S. If anybody has a copy of 07AAZ-TK8C120 and is willing to share it or its .iso file, please contact me privately.  Not sure why this got deleted, admin?

Answer (score 0):

For somebody have a newer model, audio reset code is not required and I did not receive the audio reset code from a dealer when I bought 2016 honda odyssey. After reconnect battery, you have to push audio power button for a few seconds as instructed by message. However when I lost power a few times, it did not work and audio was locked, and made warning melody. So I disconnected battery and reconnect it, and it still did not work. I tried it again and at this time waited for a few minute before reconnect it, and I was able to unlock the audio.